# How to get only keys from json response

Tags: php, arrays, mailchimp-api-v3.0

This is my json response:

```
 {
"status": 1,
"message": "Fields list!",
"dataArray": {
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "663657d6bee76fdd3285c879bf2849e2",
            "email_address": "shahzad.hussain@vaivaltech.com"
        }
    ]
 }
}
```

Here i want to get on keys that is id and email_address in response but i am also getting values of id and email 
This is my controller code:

```
          $mc = new MailChimp($apikey);
        $fields = $mc->get('/lists/'.$list_id.'/members?fields=members.id,members.email_address');
        $fields = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Fields list!', 'dataArray' => ($fields)
        ];
        return Response::json($fields, 200);
```

if  write php function array_keys like in my code 'dataArray' => ($fields)
when i hit my request it shows empty response in dataArray like this:

```
{
"status": 1,
"message": "Fields list!",
"dataArray": [
    "members"
   ]
 }
```

I am stuck here why its not showing me keys when i write array_keys function its returning nothng!
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: what is the expected output? Do you want a flat array or multidimensional?

Comment: i just want array with only keys not values yea flat array

Comment: any answer please i am stuck in this issue

Comment: I can't get "members", the rest can be done with array_keys and array_walk_recursive. https://3v4l.org/BjZ9j

Comment: can u please edit into my code

Comment: when i tried to put your code in my controller code it says json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: if you already have an array then skip that line.

Comment: Thanks i got something which i expected